# Rails - Universal Global Function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to expose a global function to all aspects of my Ruby on Rails project (models, views, and controllers). Initially, I thought that I could just add:

```
def self.my_function
    # Code here...
end
```

to /config/application.rb and then just call:

```
Application::my_function
```

anywhere in my application. But that didn't work. So I did some googling and it appears that I can expose global functions:

- For my controllers in /app/controllers/application_controller.rb
- For my views in /app/helpers/application_helper.rb
- For my models in /lib/

But not for all of them at once.

Can anybody tell me if what I want is possible?

I'd also like to avoid any include statements as much as possible as this is ideally supposed to be accessible from anywhere. But at this point, even using include statements would be OK if I can define the logic for this function in one central location.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

define it in `config/environment.rb`, before the app gets initialized with:

```
<YourApp>::Application.initialize!
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the solution! Straight and simple!